# An asymptotic expansion for MeijerG function

Tags: asymptotics

By using Mathematica

`Series[MeijerG[{{-(1/2)}, {}}, {{-(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2}, {}}, a x], {x,0, 0}, Assumptions -> a > 0]`,

I got an asymptotic expansion of MeijerG function at $x\approx 0$ for $a>0$ as 
$$G_{1,3}^{3,1}\left(a x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)\xrightarrow{} \frac{-\log (a)-\log (x)-2 \gamma }{\sqrt{a} \sqrt{x}}+O\left(\sqrt{x}\right).$$

However, with available asymptotic expression in [MeijerG](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/), I could not derive above expression.

Does anyone have an idea of deriving this?

Here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: Is the MA result correct?

Comment: I added an example plot.

Comment: You may reduce the `MeierG`to simpler functions. Have a look here Bateman, H.; Erdélyi, A. (1953). [Higher Transcendental Functions](http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf), Vol. I (PDF). New York: McGraw–Hill. (see § 5.3, "Definition of the G-Function", Eq.(32) on p. 218)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can roundtrip your expression by first finding the `MellinTransform` and then instead of applying `InverseMellinTransform`, we can just take the first residue. This ends up giving the main series term. [[formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/06/01/03/01/0003/)]

Here's the Mellin transform:

```
mei = MeijerG[{{-(1/2)}, {}}, {{-(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2}, {}}, a x];

mel = MellinTransform[mei, x, s]
```

> $-\frac{1}{2} \pi  (2 s-1) a^{-s} \sec (\pi  s) \Gamma \left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$

Now in order to find where to take the residue, we need to know the strip in which this transform exists:

```
MellinTransform[mei, x, s, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[..., 1/2 < Re[s] < 3/2]
> ```

It turns out summing residues in the complex plane to the right of the strip will diverge and so we sum to the left. This means we'll start with `s == 1/2`:

```
Residue[mel x^-s, {s, 1/2}]
```

> $\displaystyle \frac{-2\gamma - \log(a) - \log(x)}{\sqrt{a} \sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Clear explanation! Thanks @Chip Hurst.